# Calculate power of number with recursion and addition

Tags: java, recursion

I must calculate X to the power of Y with recursion and only addition. I really can't figure out how to do it without using loops or using multiplication. This is not my homework. It is a question from last years exams I am stuck on.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Season4Task7 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter X");
        int x = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter y");
        int y = sc.nextInt();

        System.out.println(findXY(x, y, 0));
    }
    static int findXY(int x, int y, int result){
        if(y==0){
            return 1;
        }
        if(x==0){
            return 0;
        }
        if(y==1){
            return result+x;
        }
        result+=x;

        return findXY(x, y-1, result);
    }
}
```

First two ifs look fine, maybe the 'y-1' as well but after that it might be incorrect, also is there a chance not to use 'int result' but only to pass x and y to the function?

Comment: You appear to be multiplying, not raising to the power. https://ideone.com/Dl9tMe

Comment: why not use 2 methods? one that 'multiplies' by recursively adding values and the second one that recursively calls the first one in order to achieve the goal?

Comment: Have not thought about using 2 methods I will try work on this now

Comment: ["Can someone help me?" is not a question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236).  Please [edit] your question to be far more specific about what help you need, so that this doesn't look like a "gimme teh codez" question.

Comment: @Georgi Joe NEVER said this is a homework, so don't get aggravated here acting as if they did, or saying they are rude when there is no rudeness in their message. They suggest to you why the phrasing isn't ideal, and say what you should do to change it... how is that bad? In any case, 3 hours before coming to Stack for your question means you are likely misusing the resource that this site is.... Stack isn't the place to turn to as soon as you get stuck. Normally you do a BUNCH of research (I personally leave my questions as draft for about 7 days as I work on them EXTENSIVELY).

Comment: Maybe you can't even read ? 'Can you help me'was my post edited from someone of you. And  yeah indeed I am not using this recourse anymore, cant handle the emo drama queens in here. Enjoy your miserable lives living in an internet forum and thinking that you are a big deal only because you have more experience from someone who is just starting.         "edit approved 10 hours ago Kumar"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since we cannot using multiplication, we need to use recursive addition. check my code below. Your first 3 if conditions are correct. Modify the later code to below method.

```
package com.java;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Season4Task7 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter X");

        int x = sc.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Enter y");

        int y = sc.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Final :: " + findXPowerY(x, y));

        sc.close();
    }

    static int findXPowerY(int x, int y) {

        if (y == 0) {
            return 1;
        }
        if (x == 0) {
            return 0;
        }
        if (y == 1) {
            return x;
        }

        return multiply(x, findXPowerY(x, y - 1));
    }

    static int multiply(int x, int y) {
        if (y != 0)
            return (x + multiply(x, y - 1));
        else
            return 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What your `findXY` method really does is simple multiplication, not exponentiation. First of all, it could be improved from using 3 parameters to only 2:

```
static int findXY(int x, int y){
    if(y==0){
        return 1;
    }
    if(x==0){
        return 0;
    }
    if(y==1){
        return x;
    }

    return x + findXY(x, y-1);
}
```

Secondly, you are halfway done! You just found a way to multiply with only using addition and recursion. What you now need to do, is call this multiplication certain numer of times, again, using recursion.

Before we start, let's rename the method from `findXY` to `multiply`, since it better indicates its intent and functionality.

Thirdly, we need to implement the method that calculates the power. Keeping in mind that we *renamed* your `findXY` method to `multiply` and changed the number of parameters from 3 to 2, our implementation might look like this:

```
static int power(int x, int y) {
    if(y == 0) {
        return 1;
    }
    if(y == 1) {
        return x;
    }
    return x * power(x, y-1));
}
```

Hey, but we are **not** allowed to use multiplication! Fortunately, we made our own implementation! The final product looks like this:

```
static int power(int x, int y) {
    if(y == 0) {
        return 1;
    }
    if(y == 1) {
        return x;
    }
    return multiply(x, power(x, y-1));
}
```

Please do note that this approach does not work with negative numbers. If they are the case, you could wrap this method in another one that simply calls `power` with `abs` value and inverts the result

Comment: @GeorgiMichev it appears that you deleted the comment and unchecked this answer as accepted. Does this solution have a flaw that does not satisfy what you asked about?

Comment: I am sorry it is complicated for me, especially with method name changed, I don't think I understand the code clearly. You are using two methods or ? Because if its only the last one it is not working ...

Comment: Yes, I explained it in my answer that I am using 2 methods. `multiply` method is the modified version of your `findXY` and `power` uses that method. What exactly is the part you are having troubles understanding?